# Which was our thousandth question?

Tags: discussion

I just happened to check Area 51 and noticed that we've reached precisely 1000 questions! I think their counts can have a short lag though, so I'm not sure if the most recent question asked on Statistical Analysis was the thousandth question. Could someone (a moderator?) find out what was, if that's possible? (This is pure numerological curiousity and of course totally baseist. StackOverflow no doubt celebrated their 1024th question. Or even waited until the 65536th.)

Comment: We should wait for the 1960th question before celebrating!

Comment: Hmm, maybe we should choose a random number between, say, 1000 and 2000 and conceal it until it is reached to reduce the risk of someone gaming the system  to acquire the fame and riches that will inevitably follow once the media pick up on this milestone...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming the count is correct, the 1000th question was [How to know which probability distribution to expect?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/4053/159)

Comment: That was 6 years ago. 100,000 is coming soon.